# I am trying to fill in a login automatically but keep getting NoSuchElementException

Tags: python, xpath, input, webdriver

I am trying to log in for testing to https://betwarrior.bet/en/login but keep getting no such element exceptions for the email section...

I have tried with absolute xpath but no luck.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome('path')
browser.get('https://betwarrior.bet/en/login')

a = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//div/div/div[3]/main/div/form/div[2]/div/div/input')

a.send_keys('abc')
```

If any of you could send me an example how do I insert a username that would be much appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: check if element has ID and use it instead of long string in xpath. Or try short `"//input"` at start. Mostly long xpath is not needed to get element.

Comment: you can alos check if element is in `<iframe>`. To get element in `<iframe>` you would have to use first `browser.switch_to.frame`

Comment: not in a frame and doesn't have an ID, it has a class, but class_name gives the same exception...

Comment: I can't open it - I see message "not available in your location". I would start with `//input` to see if it can find tag. I would also observe if it displays exception before browser displays element. Maybe it needs `time.sleep()` to wait till JavaScript render element.

Comment: the website only avail from South America. I have tried the sleep bit... did not help...

Comment: did you check `xpath("//input")`. You can also get page as text `browser.page_source` and check manually if there is your class. `page_source` is a string so you can try string function to find its position `pos = browser.page_source.find("your_class")`, and display it `print(browser.page_source[pos:pos+20])`